# WCF callback is strangely invoked?

Tags: c#, wcf

In my company we have windows services hosted under some service user. 
Service "A" is working great. It can be accessed and called. But for service "B" there is problem I don't know how to solve.

If I host service "B" localy there is no problems in calling function, but if I host it on server, it just "partially" works. Some events in callback implementation are called but other isn't.

**Important to mention context:**

IT WORKED. It worked before some windows updates. Contracts were changed (Result class were changed), but was updated, and it seems like they are cached somewhere...

I tried to enable trace on client and server, and see what is going on, but no success. No errors/warnings, nothing.

```
public interface IProcessingCallback
{
    void OnStatus(Status s); //all good, constantly called
    void OnResult(Result r); //never called
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No, nothing at all.